# Buying Land and tree cleaning

Tags: cleaning

I want to buy land in the Alameda County in California.  The land I saw on the market has lots of trees.   I am not looking for big development but just a small parcel <.5 acre for a single family house.
 - What are the general procedure for tree cleaning?
 - Does contractor also do tree cleaning?
 - What else should I keep an eye out other than zoning?

Thanks

Comment: A contractor can clear trees, But first make sure it is legal to take them out. A friend of mine did some work that included cutting 3 or 4 trees down in another county / town and had a huge hassle because he was supposed to get a permit. I cant remember of it was by size or number of trees or some combination of both that required the permit.

Comment: Definitely check with the city/county about a permit. I own a house in central Florida in a city with an 'arbor ordinance' and a have to get a permit to cut down any trees. I usually have to plant replacements too or make a 'donation to the arbor bank'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Cut them down & haul the corpses away. But, the Governing Body may limit how much you can clear & your Architect or Builder will have other requirements.

2- Yes, the Contractor is there to do whatever it takes to get your money, he'll Sub-Contract the tree removal out to an experienced guy or firm.

3- Electricity, Septic System, Heating Oil or Gas (if not electric), 911 Service, Fire Dept. access or abilities & thereby Insurance Costs, Environmental Impact Control Costs, Water Retention & Driveway Path...meaning, will it be easy for many vehicles to park or big long trucks to deliver materials or will costs & problems arise from difficult access.